# Displaying a list of items with varying height

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list with a RecyclerView of items with various heights. I want the scrollbar to behave like a normal scrollbar, to have a fixed height that scrolls smoothly from the top of the page and to the bottom as the user scrolls through the list.

I am attempting to use a custom RecyclerView and calling computeVerticalScrollExtent and computeVerticalScrollRange directly but these methods behave erratically.

```
@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollExtent() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
    return sizeOfList;
}
```

Typically sizeOfList is somewhere around 20. For some reason when I scroll down the scrollbar immediately jumps to the bottom of the screen and stays there while I continue to scrolldown. I can solve this by making sizeOfList somewhere around 500. I'm not sure why this is the case since the docs claim that the units I defined will be the ones used. If I attempt to use computeVerticalScrollOffset the scrollbar never moves.

> ```
> /**
>  * <p>Compute the vertical extent of the vertical scrollbar's thumb within the vertical range.
>  * This value is used to compute the length of the thumb within the scrollbar's track.</p>
>  *
>  * <p>The range is expressed in arbitrary units that must be the same as the units used by
>  * {@link #computeVerticalScrollRange()} and {@link #computeVerticalScrollOffset()}.</p>
>  *
>  * <p>Default implementation returns 0.</p>
>  *
>  * <p>If you want to support scroll bars, override
>  * {@link RecyclerView.LayoutManager#computeVerticalScrollExtent(RecyclerView.State)} in your
>  * LayoutManager.</p>
> ```

This is from the RecyclerView docs. I'm not sure what the last line means since scrollbars do work for the most part and the docs for that do not explain anything further. I've tried experimenting with this and have not had any success.

The only explanation of this method is

> Override this method if you want to support scroll bars.

Which doesn't help.